# Error when installing using "pip3 install xgboost"

Tags: python-3.x, macos, command-line, installation, xgboost

I tried to follow this guide: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html
But I got these error messages.  Any insights?

(base) MacBook-Pro-2:~ Prajnajiang$ pip3 install xgboost
Collecting xgboost
  Using cached xgboost-1.0.2.tar.gz (821 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/5y/6cyzpgbx7895mzf3wfvryvrr0000gn/T/pip-install-quq3h_3t/xgboost/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/5y/6cyzpgbx7895mzf3wfvryvrr0000gn/T/pip-install-quq3h_3t/xgboost/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/5y/6cyzpgbx7895mzf3wfvryvrr0000gn/T/pip-install-quq3h_3t/xgboost/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/5y/6cyzpgbx7895mzf3wfvryvrr0000gn/T/pip-install-quq3h_3t/xgboost/
    Complete output (27 lines):
    ++ pwd
    + oldpath=/private/var/folders/5y/6cyzpgbx7895mzf3wfvryvrr0000gn/T/pip-install-quq3h_3t/xgboost
    + cd ./xgboost/
    + mkdir -p build
    + cd build
    + cmake ..
    ./xgboost/build-python.sh: line 21: cmake: command not found
    + echo -----------------------------
    -----------------------------
    + echo 'Building multi-thread xgboost failed'
    Building multi-thread xgboost failed
    + echo 'Start to build single-thread xgboost'
    Start to build single-thread xgboost
    + cmake .. -DUSE_OPENMP=0
    ./xgboost/build-python.sh: line 27: cmake: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "/private/var/folders/5y/6cyzpgbx7895mzf3wfvryvrr0000gn/T/pip-install-quq3h_3t/xgboost/setup.py", line 42, in 
        LIB_PATH = libpath'find_lib_path'
      File "/private/var/folders/5y/6cyzpgbx7895mzf3wfvryvrr0000gn/T/pip-install-quq3h_3t/xgboost/xgboost/libpath.py", line 50, in find_lib_path
        'List of candidates:\n' + ('\n'.join(dll_path)))
    XGBoostLibraryNotFound: Cannot find XGBoost Library in the candidate path, did you install compilers and run build.sh in root path?
    List of candidates:
    /private/var/folders/5y/6cyzpgbx7895mzf3wfvryvrr0000gn/T/pip-install-quq3h_3t/xgboost/xgboost/libxgboost.dylib
    /private/var/folders/5y/6cyzpgbx7895mzf3wfvryvrr0000gn/T/pip-install-quq3h_3t/xgboost/xgboost/../../lib/libxgboost.dylib
    /private/var/folders/5y/6cyzpgbx7895mzf3wfvryvrr0000gn/T/pip-install-quq3h_3t/xgboost/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.dylib
    /Users/apple/opt/anaconda3/xgboost/libxgboost.dylib
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem resolved:
The issue was that I did not have cmake installed. After installing cmake, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and this solved it by installing `cmake`:

```
pip install cmake
```